# How to do async Windows Service ExecuteAsync properly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await

## The Background

I'm writing a Windows Service to collect status updates from automated tasks.  Updates are issued via UDP broadcast.  In addition, there is a management UI (hosting in the Windows Service) which provides access to the collected status updates.

## The Relevent Code

Irrelevent code has been removed for readability.

### Program.cs

```cs
namespace NotificationHub.Service {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);
            builder.Services.AddWindowsService(options => {
                options.ServiceName = "Notification Hub Service";
            });
            //  SETUP DI (removed for readability)

            IHost host = builder.Build();
            host.Start();
            host.WaitForShutdown();
        }   //  Main()
    }       //  Program
}           //  ns
```

### WindowsBackgroundService : BackgroundService

```cs
using System.Net.Sockets;
using NotificationHub.Service.Services.Management;
using NotificationHub.Service.Services.NotificationHub;

namespace NotificationHub.Service {
    public class WindowsBackgroundService : BackgroundService {
        public const int EXIT_DO_NOT_EXIT = -1;
        public const int EXIT_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION = 1024;
        public const int EXIT_SOCKET_EXCEPTION = 32;

        private readonly NotificationHubService _hubService;
        private readonly ManagementService _managementService;
        private readonly ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> _logger;


        public WindowsBackgroundService(NotificationHubService hubService, ManagementService managementService, ILogger<WindowsBackgroundService> logger) {
            _hubService = hubService;
            _managementService = managementService;
            _logger = logger;
        }



        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken) {
            stoppingToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            _logger.LogInformation("Service started at: {ServiceStartTime}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            try {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {RunningTime}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                _hubService.ListenForUdpMessages();
                _managementService.ListenForHttpConnections();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "{Message}", ex.Message);

                int exit = EXIT_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION;
                Type exType = ex.GetType();
                switch (exType) {
                    case Type _ when exType == typeof(TaskCanceledException):
                        //  Exception generated via net stop or some other expected shutdown method.
                        //  Nothing to do.
                        exit = EXIT_DO_NOT_EXIT;
                        break;

                    case Type _ when exType == typeof(SocketException):
                        exit = EXIT_SOCKET_EXCEPTION;
                        break;

                    default:
                        exit = EXIT_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION;
                        break;
                }

                if (EXIT_DO_NOT_EXIT != exit) {
                    Environment.Exit(exit);
                }
            }
        }   //      ExecuteAsync()
    }       //  WindowsBackgroundService
}           //  ns
```

### NotificationHubService.ListenForUdpMessages()

```cs
namespace NotificationHub.Service.Services.NotificationHub {
    public sealed class NotificationHubService {
        public async void ListenForUdpMessages() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    UdpReceiveResult receiveResult = await _udp.ReceiveAsync();
                    byte[] bytes = receiveResult.Buffer;
                    //  ADDITIONAL PROCESSING HERE (removed for readability)
                } catch (SocketException sockEx) {
                    //  Likely caused by the service shutting down.
                    _logger.LogWarning(sockEx, "{Message}", sockEx.Message);
                }
            }
        }   //  ListenForUdpMessages
    }       //  NotificationHubService
}           //  ns
```

### ManagementService.ListenForHttpConnections()

```cs
namespace NotificationHub.Service.Services.Management {
    public class ManagementService {
        public async void ListenForHttpConnections() {
            _logger.LogInformation($"Starting HttpListener.");
            _http.Start();
            while (true) {
                HttpListenerContext httpContext = await _http.GetContextAsync();
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(HandleHttpContext, httpContext, false);
            }
        }   //  ListenForHttpConnections()



        public void HandleHttpContext(HttpListenerContext context) {
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            //  PROCESS THE REQUEST & WRITE THE RESPONSE (removed for readability)
            response.OutputStream.Close();
        }   //  HandleHttpContext()
    }       //  ManagementService
}           //  ns
```

## The Problem

`WindowsBackgroundService.ExecuteAsync()` calls the startup methods (`ListenFor*()`) on the two sub-services (`NotificationHubService` and `ManagementService`).  These startup methods basically run forever (infinite loops) on their own threads, so `WindowsBackgroundService.ExecuteAsync()` continues on it's merry way and quickly exits to `host.WaitForShutdown()` in **Program.Main()**.

So as-is, none of my error handling (try/catch) in **WindowsBackgroundService.ExecuteAsync()** ever gets hit.

I believe I am doing something wrong related to async... but I'm really not sure.

My goal right now is to detect when the **WindowsBackgroundService** is shutting down so I can add some logging/flush various mamory caches to disk and perform a graceful shutdown.  Any thoughts on what I have done wrong?

Comment: async is not multithreaded.  What do you want to happen here?  Neither of your async methods ever end.  You could use `await` to wait for one of the asyncs to exit (which they never will).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058#avoid-async-void). `async void` is intended for event handlers; most other usages are misuses. `async Task` is the natural signature for an `async` method without a return value.

So, change `ListenForUdpMessages` and `ListenForHttpConnections` to be `async Task` instead of `async void`.

This then brings up the question: "what should I do with those tasks?". Your `ExecuteAsync` calls both those methods; it should do something with them. `await`ing them one at a time is not a good idea, because you want them both running concurrently. The solution for asynchronous concurrency is to use `Task.WhenAll`, something like this:

```
_logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {RunningTime}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
var udpTask = _hubService.ListenForUdpMessages();
var httpTask = _managementService.ListenForHttpConnections();
await Task.WhenAll(udpTask, httpTask);
```

And now your exception handling in `ExecuteAsync` will work for exceptions propagated from those methods.

Side notes:

- "there is a management UI (hosting in the Windows Service)" - I hope you mean  the management UI *connects* to the Win32 service, and that the Win32 service does not provide a UI directly. Win32 services providing UIs has been frowned upon for decades and I'm not sure if it's even possible with modern versions of Windows.
- You have a "main loop with independent workers" kind of pattern going on in your HTTP listener. I strongly recommend self-hosting ASP.NET instead. If you really do need your own main loop with independent workers, then I recommend using something like my [structured concurrency library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/StructuredConcurrency) to manage the workers rather than just throwing them on the thread pool.

Comment: Stephen, thank you so much!  This looks exactly like the piece I was missing.  Sure do appreciate it!    As to your side notes:  1) The "management UI" is a web server (HttpListener).  It is not a Win32 UI.  Perhaps "UI" was a bit of a misnomer.    2)  I will absolutely look in to your structured concurrency library.  Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Hmmm, excuse my ignorance please.. but what should the `async Task ListenForUdpMessages()` method look like?  How do I construct the task? (Task.CompletedTask and Task.FromResult doesn't seem appropriate), and when do I return that Task?   Thank you!

Comment: I ended up returning `Task.Factory.StartNew()` from each of the sub-services.  Seems to work ok so far.

Comment: I thought about hosting aspnet myself, but I decided against it so that the aspnet runtime didn't need to be installed.   While HttpListener is more work, it saves disk space and makes deployment lighter.   I may find that these assumptions don't hold in the future.  I'm open to being wrong.

Comment: You don't need to return the task. Just change `async void` to `async Task` and that's it.